Can any point process be thinned into a Poisson point process?
Is the following true?  For any point process $X$ there exists a procedure $\mathcal{P}$ and a (homogenous) Poisson point process $Y$ with intensity $\lambda > 0$ such that the process of drawing a realization from $X$ and applying $\mathcal{P}$ to it is indistinguishable from the process of drawing a realization from $Y$ .
Note that I am only asking about the existence of $\mathcal{P}$ and $Y$, not whether $\mathcal{P}$ is practical.
I have looked at Møller & Schoenberg (2010) and especially Schoenberg (2009), trying to see if and how the existence of $\mathcal{P}$ could be extracted from $\mathcal{P}$ being practical.  I have also reviewed literature on independent thinning of point processes.
Edit 1: I think $X$ will need to be a stationary point process. Otherwise here is a counter-example: Construct $X$ on $[0,\infty)$ by specifying that on each interval $[n-1,n)$ for positive integers $n$, there is a Poisson point process of intensity $1/n$.
Edit 2: A common approach to thinning is $p$-thinning, in which each point $X_i$ is retained with probability $p(X_i)$ and deleted otherwise. It appears that (independent?) $p$-thinning will not necessarily yield a Poisson point process - for example, (independent?) $p$-thinning of a mixed binomial process will yield another mixed binomial process. So procedure $\mathcal{P}$ may need to be more sophisticated (... for this question, the interest is only in the existence of a Poisson point process after thinning).
Edit 3: Goldman (1967) has a limit theorem and sufficient conditions for $p$-thinning a stationary point process into a mixed Poisson process. So can any mixed Poisson process (or close approximation) be thinned into a homogenous Poisson process of intensity $\lambda > 0$?
References
Møller, J., & Schoenberg, F. P. (2010). Thinning Spatial Point Processes into Poisson Processes. Advances in Applied Probability, 42(2), 347–358.
Goldman, Jay R. (1967, June). Stochastic Point Processes: Limit Theorems. Ann. Math. Statist. 38(3), 771-779.
Schoenberg, F. P. (2009). On thinning a spatial point process into a Poisson process using the Papangelou intensity.

Try thinking in terms of the underlying random measure; what kind of measure is represented by a point process?

Hi @RandySavage: I understand that a point process represents a random counting measure: Let $N$ be a random counting measure. Then for $A$ measurable, $N(A)$ is the random variable that counts the number of points in $A$. My further understanding is that if random counting measure $M$ corresponds to a homogenous Poisson point process of intensity $\lambda$ then for any collection of disjoint, bounded Borel sets ${A_j}_j$, $M(A_j)$ are independent Poisson random variables of rate $\lambda$. But I don’t have any idea how to infer the existence of $M$ from $N$?

For any s-finite measure $\mu$ there exists a poison process with intensity measure $\mu$ - see theorem 3.6 here for a proof. If the measure in question is deterministic, then we have a fixed intensity measure and thus a Poisson process - if the measure is random, then we have a Cox process, or a Poisson process with a random intensity measure. For some sufficient conditions for a Cox process to be thinned to a poisson process, check out exercise 13.5 in the same notes.

Hello @RandySavage: I think I'm not understanding something.  Exercise 13.5 seems to be about taking a Cox process over a space and restricting it to a sub-space ?  I also looked at Exercise 13.15: Given a proper point process $\eta$, if $\eta_p$ is a $p$-thinning of $\eta$ and $\eta_p$ and $\eta - \eta_p$ are independent then $\eta$ is a Poisson process ?  (Thanks for your patience.)

Whoops, that was a typo on my part, I meant 3.15! That gives a sufficient condition for a p-thinning of a cox process to be poisson. Intuitively, it’s a higher dimensional extension of the independent increments property that characterizes poisson processes on the real line.
Getting back to the original question, I think the main factor is whether the procedure P is independent of the underlying process. If the fidis of X are dependent on some unknown stochastic element, then the same P won’t necessarily result in a poisson process for all realizations of X without conditioning
